(TESTING) Knowledge Agent - AI-powered Stack Exchange Integration
About
Knowledge Agent is an AI-powered assistant that integrates with Stack Exchange to provide intelligent programming assistance and knowledge retrieval. It's part of a project which aims to enhance AI agents' ability to autonomously access and utilize external knowledge sources.
Features

Autonomous knowledge retrieval from Stack Exchange
Intelligent query processing and context understanding
Integration with other knowledge sources (Wikipedia, Wolfram Alpha, arXiv)
Caching and vector storage for efficient knowledge reuse
Asynchronous operation for improved performance

Technical Details

Language: Python 3.8+
Key Libraries:

stackapi (Stack Exchange API wrapper)
chromadb (vector storage)
asyncio (asynchronous operations)
requests (HTTP client)



Authentication
This application uses Stack Exchange OAuth 2.0 for authentication with the following scopes:

read_inbox
write_access
private_info

Platform & Requirements

Operating Systems: Cross-platform (Windows, macOS, Linux)
Python 3.8 or higher
Required Python packages are managed via pip/requirements.txt

License
MIT License
Support
For support or questions, please open an issue on our GitHub repository.
Privacy
The application only accesses Stack Exchange data as needed for knowledge retrieval and respects all Stack Exchange API usage guidelines and quotas.
